# How can I remove this image in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, images

I got this Excel file from a coworker, who asked me to remove an image that was stuck. I used the file to create this gif:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/PneivST.gifv]

When I click on it, it overlaps the image behind it but I cannot delete it. Dragging it does nothing. Right clicking also does nothing.

What kind of image is this, and what can I do to remove it?

Comment: try to copy the whole content of the sheet (CTRL+A) to another sheet, maybe there you can delete it.

Comment: The image could be set to be Sent to back or the file might be protected from editing

Comment: Press ALT-F11 to open the VBA Editor and see if there's any code attached to the image. Remove it and try again.

Comment: The file was indeed in read-only mode when I made the gif, but saving a new copy to my computer and editing that one did not help.

I checked for code, and there was no code attached to the image.

@MátéJuhász Your solution is the one I ended up using. When I used CTRL+A to copy the entire sheet, that image did not get copied with everything else. 

Thank you all for your help. As of now I still have no clue what caused this image to be any different from the others.

Comment: If these images are part of a gif, you cannot just click it and delete because it is part of the image itself. Probably be easier to delete the gif and start over.

Comment: @CharlieRB I created the gif using the Excel file that my coworker sent me in order to more clearly show the problem. I have edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Oh, gottcha. So you are not actually working with a gif, only using one to illustrate the problem you are having? Sure didn't read that way initially.

Comment: If you open the Developer Tab and then the Design Mode button, are you then able to select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I copied the entire sheet to a new one. The image did not copy to the new sheet. I was then able to re-format the other images so that they fit correctly.

Answer (score -3):

From my understanding, it looks like the image is in the bottom cell. Try using VBA to clear that specific cell.

Range("O25").ClearContents

Comment: This does not answer the question on how to remove the image itself.

Comment: I made the gif myself with the Excel file that was sent to me.

Comment: My apology, in the question you never mentioned that. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: In Excel images are not "in cells". `Range.ClearContents` removes formula / constant from the cell only.